# skipping cin.get() and cin.ignore()

Tags: c++, cin

For some reason, my program is skipping the code fragments `cin.get();` and `cin.ignore();`. I do not know why this is happening, because the two fragments work fine when just inside the main() scope, and not in the if statement.

Here is the relevent code fragment:

```
input.open(inputFileName);
if (input.fail())
{
    cout << "Error: failed to open '" << inputFileName << "'.\n\n";
    cout << "Press '' to end the program...";
    cin.get(); //cin.ignore() also does nothing.
    input.close();
    exit(1);
}
```

The rest of the source code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/xy0qMvBq

Comment: Most likely it's because there's already some input in the input buffer. So the operation completes immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cin >> inputFileName;
```

With that command, the user is going to type some "stuff", and then hit enter.  That's going to put the "stuff", plus a newline character into the input buffer.  Then the "stuff" is going to get stored into inputFileName, and the newline character is going to be left there.  This is what cin.get() and cin.ignore() read, they are not being skipped.

Comment: That's what I figured. But when adding 'cin.clear()' after `cin >> inputFileName`, 'cin.get()' still fails to pause the program. Am I mistake that 'cin.clear()' clears the input buffer? If so, what would I use to clear the input buffer?

Comment: @JonRurka: No, `cin.clear()` does not clear the input buffer.  It clears the error flags on cin, and I see no reason to believe that you should have any errors.  There actually is no reliable way to clear the input buffer.  But, you could use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` in order to ignore characters until the newline.  In your case, you could just call `cin.ignore()` twice (instead of once).  Or `cin.ignore()` followed by `cin.get()`.

Comment: having two 'cin.ignore();' lines worked perfectly. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The part of the code posted by you is absolutely working fine and cin.get() is not bieng ignored in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
std::string dummy;
getline(std::cin,dummy);
```

or (if you didnt allready):

```
cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
```

cin.ignore(1000,'\n'); removes all characters in the cin buffer, until it finds a '\n' character in the cin buffer or reaches the maximum of ignored/removed characters (1000 in this case).

Comment: It does not wait 500 ms, it waits for 500 characters. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/